# wp_enqueue_script - file path in rendered page source code missing "/"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to add javascript to the footer of a wordpress page using wp_enqueue_script in the functions file of a child theme.

I have never done this before so am a bit of a novice to using wp_enqueue_script but have read a fair few similar posts on the Stackoverflow forum but haven't found anything that resolves my issue, which is . . . the file source url is missing a "/" between the `get_theme_file_uri()` part of the path and the remaining folderstructure.

I have inserted this code into the functions file:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'reactionform_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'includes/js/reactionform_js.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

.

However, when i look at the source code on the rendered page the file path is `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.futureproofpromotions.com/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Themeincludes/js/reactionform_js.js?ver=5.2.4'></script>` which is missing the / between the theme's root folder `Avada-Child-Theme` & the `includes` folder? FYI The error message on Chrome developer tools says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I have also tried `get_theme_file_uri()` as opposed to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` but no luck! I have also tried adding the forward slash (/) like this `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/'. 'includes/js/reactionform_js.js'` but also no luck.

I would appreciate if anyone could explain how to resolve this issue.

Also . . . as far as I understand, I believe I need to include `, '' , '', true` after the $scr argument for the javascript to show in the footer instead of the header. However, at the moment when I include those arguments various parts of the page don't load, so have left those out until I at least get the script to load somewhere on the page. Once I have that, I'll add those arguments which hopefully will complete the task.

I am using:
Wordpress: v 5.2.4
Avada Theme: v 6.1
php version 7.2.23
MySQL version: 5.5.62

Many thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you (I have this config in my theme and it does), try using the `get_template_directory_uri()` function instead:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'reactionform_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/reactionform_js.js', array(), false, true );
```

with the last param (footer) to `true`, you could see the function signature:

```
function wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src = '', $deps = array(), $ver = false, $in_footer = false ) {
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thx JP - tried your suggestion, but goes to template theme rather than child theme (still with the file path structure missing / between theme folder & Includes folder). Also . . . when including those extra arguments you gave ( `, array(), false, true`) it moved script to footer but when using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get to child theme, other elements on page didn't load as before. 

This area is new to me but Is it something to do with validating/registering something before you enqueue the script?

Comment: OK, I've managed to sort this now. I discovered that having the minify option ticked on the website's WP 3 Total Cache plugin was stopping the entire functions file in the child theme from working! Once that was switched off - everything worked fine. Thx JP for your help and the additional arguments which work well & place the script in the footer too.

Comment: Your welcome! Try to update your question with your answer to help others and upvote/close the question if it helped you.

Comment: Solved - in fact the reason the `/` was missing from the script src url was because the WP 3 Total Cache plugin installed on the same website had the minify option enabled! This seemed to be messing up the src url for both `theme_enqueue_scripts()` in the child theme's functions.php file and when the minify option was disabled on the WP 3 Total Cache plugin, all enqueueing functions worked fine. Also, just for the record, It didn't mess up the `my_custom_head_function_for_avada()` function also in the file - that one was OK